# Proof of convergence of a geometric power series

Tags: self-learning

While reading a time series analysis textebook I've stumbled upon an assertion which I struggle to understand.

If $|a|<1$ then
$1 + a+ a^2 + a^3 + ... + a^n$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-a}$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

A reference to a clear proof would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look up [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one to be pretty straight forward: http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/complexgeometricseries/ComplexGeometricSeriesTheorem.1.pdf